# How to SCP selected files from a server

Tags: linux, command-line, command

I have a simple question. How do I download, for example only json files, from a folder in the server.

the following code is what i use and it downloads everything.

```
scp -r name:server:folder_name .
```

I would like to add some filtering so I can download only selected files, for example if the file ends with `.json` or `.wav`

Comment: This is an end-users tool question and off-topic for Stackoverflow where the focus is on programming code problems.. Please delete here and repost to https://superuser.com. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Use wildcards**

```
scp name:server:~/{*.json,*.wav} .
```

> Commands can use wildcards to perform actions on more than one file at a time, or to find part of a phrase in a text file.
>
> Source: [TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm)